# xaDataSource for authentication?

Tags: java, spring, security

I'm using Spring Security to provide the ability for user authentication and basically I'm using `XA-datasource` to perform a data operations. Is it good to use the datatsource to perform user-authentication in the sense of perfromance? There won't be distributed transactions in the user authentication.

So would it be better to define another `non-XA-datasource` to perform such operations in the performance point of view? Now, my security config looks like

```
<!-- The datasource is defined in a separate config file -->
<bean id="xaDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/xaCoreDS">
</bean>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="xaDataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
      authorities-by-username-query=
        "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the XAdatasource will be less performant in transactional mode. But the authentication manager use only select request and might be use non-transactional calls. So The transactional proces and the two phase commit will not be used. For me there's no need to define a `non-XA-datasource`